# How to create 3D reconstruction of a tube from the inside using a single video feed?

Tags: matlab, opencv, video, 3d, camera

I would like to create a 3D reconstruction of the inside of a tube. Most 3D reconstructions capture many pictures from different angles around an object. However, in my project, I have monocular vision, a camera that can only move forward. I would like to convert this video from one camera to a 3D model of the surroundings. The model would not need to be color or be extremely precise - a mesh model is enough. Currently, I am using VisualSfM which is a great tool.

My Setup:
I have rolled up a yoga mat to form a long dark tube. Next, I attached a webcam and a flashlight to one end of a stick. I move this assembly into one end of my tube and record 20 seconds of video, slowly pushing the camera/flashlight unit into the tube. Then I use Matlab to split the video into image frames to get around 200 pictures. I upload these pictures to Visual SfM and use the pairwise sequence matching and continue with a sparse then dense reconstruction.

Currently, I am using VisualSfM which is a great tool. The problem is that since the light moves with the camera, each frame has the same lighting and looks the same. VisualSfM knows the camera is moving(shown in picture) but stacks the point clouds so it looks 2D. I would like it to form a hollow cylinder.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this problem? Do I need to change any parameters in VisualSfM? If so how?

If you can do it using OpenCV, I am open to suggestions with that too.

Thanks for your help.
 [image: Side View of Result]

Comment: if the texture of the object looks the same everywhere it is probably not solvable by parameters. Maybe add some motion sensors to the pole.

Comment: If possible, you can try to use a fixed light source instead of a light source moving with the camera.